# Python equivalent of MATLAB's "bitrevorder" function

Tags: python, matlab, signal-processing, fft

As the question suggests, does anyone know of a python equivalent function of MATLAB's **bitrevorder** function.

Reference Here -

https://uk.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/bitrevorder.html

I have searched the NumPy library for a function but cannot find anything similar.

Answer (score 1):

*Edit:* Removing my manual implementation as this is included in the scipy package as `digitrevorder` prior to 0.7.0, when the sandbox folder was removed: https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/maintenance/0.6.x/scipy/sandbox/image/transforms.py#L224

There may be a newer implementation in the recent versions - I'm not sure.